# Maven Dependencies and classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a parent artifact in my pom that is responsible for auto configuring a few properties based on `@ConditionOnClass` annotation. It also happens that I have a dependency of the same class which when included is causing some errors, even though I have not autowired any instance of the same in the code. This means that just including the dependency causes the `@ConditionOnClass` annotation to evaluate to true.

Does this mean that including the dependency automatically loads the classes of that jar in the classpath ? I do not have a clear understanding of how class loading works with Maven dependencies. Any pointer to relevant documentation or explanation of the same would be really useful.

Comment: classloading is well classloading, how you obtain de references doesn't matter. So if you add a dependency the classes are obviously on the classpath (that is the whole point of adding a dependency).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I think I made a mistake in my assumption. The dependencies are automatically added in the class path so that they can be used in the program. This will also automatically result in ConditionalOnClass to evaluate to true. How we add beans for those classes to the Application Context factory, is independent of class loading. Is my understanding correct ?